# Send images in Loop using pascal

Tags: sockets, pascal, lazarus

I am using Lazarus and i am trying to send Images in a loop from server to client. now i have an issue, it just does not send and it just freezes my Computer along the line. I do not seem to understand and know why this is so instead it just hangs my Computer

Code for the sender is given below :

**Sender**

```
unit ScreenCapClassEx;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls, ssockets ,windows;

type

  { TForm1 }

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
     FAbort: Boolean;
  public

  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure DrawCursor (ACanvas:TCanvas; Position:TPoint) ;
var
  HCursor : THandle;
begin
  HCursor := GetCursor;
  DrawIconEx(ACanvas.Handle, Position.X, Position.Y,
              HCursor, 32, 32, 0, 0, DI_NORMAL) ;
end;

function CaptureWindow(const WindowHandle: HWnd): Graphics.TBitmap;
var
  DC: HDC;
  wRect: TRect;
  CurPos: TPoint;
begin
  DC := GetWindowDC(WindowHandle);
  Result := Graphics.TBitmap.Create;
  Result.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
  try
    GetWindowRect(WindowHandle, wRect);
    Result.Width := wRect.Right - wRect.Left;
    Result.Height := wRect.Bottom - wRect.Top;
    BitBlt(Result.Canvas.Handle,
           0,
           0,
           Result.Width,
           Result.Height,
           DC,
           0,
           0,
           SRCCOPY);
    GetCursorPos(CurPos);
    DrawCursor(Result.Canvas, CurPos);
  finally
    ReleaseDC(WindowHandle, DC);
  end;
end;

procedure DoCapture;
var
  Socket: TInetSocket;
  Bmp: Graphics.TBitmap;
  FAbort: Boolean;
begin
  { Create the socket now and free it only when you're done with it}
  Socket:= TInetSocket.Create('loopback',4800);
  try
    { You need some "scape". Infinite loops are ... bad }
    while (not FAbort) and (not Application.Terminated) do begin
      Bmp := CaptureWindow(GetDesktopWindow);
      try
        Bmp.Canvas.Changed;
        Socket.Write(Bmp,1000553);
      finally
         {If you don't do this, you'll consume all the memory}
        Bmp.Free;
      end;
      Application.ProcessMessages;
    end;
  finally
    Socket.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if Assigned(Sender) and Sender.InheritsFrom(TControl) then begin
    { Use the button to start/stop capture,
      using the button's Tag as a flag to know in which mode we are. }
    if (Sender as TControl).Tag < 0 then begin
       FAbort := True;
       (Sender as TControl).Caption := '&Start capture';
       (Sender as TControl).Tag := 0;
    end else begin
       FAbort := False;
       (Sender as TControl).Caption := '&Stop capture';
       (Sender as TControl).Tag := -1;
    end;
    DoCapture;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Now the code to receive the image in a Loop as well, tho this hangs my computer is looking like this :

```
unit screenShowClassEx;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls,
  windows, ssockets;

type

    { TMyServer }

  TMyServer=class(TInetServer)
  public
  end;

{ TMyServer }

  { TForm1 }

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Image1: TImage;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private

  public

  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

procedure receiveImage();
var
 Server: TInetServer;
 Bmp: Graphics.TBitmap;
 JpegImage: TJpegImage;

begin
            Server := TMyServer.Create('loopback', 4800);
            showmessage('ok i am receiving now');
            while true do
            begin
            Server.StartAccepting;
            // show image on imagebox where Image1 :Timage
            JpegImage.Assign(Bmp);
            Form1.Image1.Canvas.Draw(0,0,JpegImage);
end;
end;

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  receiveImage();
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;
end.
```

Why is this so?? Please I do need help here

Comment: On which line exactly does the app hang?  In any case, trying to send the image from inside the gui thread is not the thing to do.  Once you've captured the bitmap, you should sent it to a backgound thread and send it from there.  Btw, having to use `Application.ProcessMessages` is usually a sign that you're not doing things right.

Comment: what am i missing then?

Comment: A background thread to receive the captured image and write it to the socket.

Comment: @MartynA, Pls i would be glad if you show me where i am getting it wrong, at least programmatically

Comment: I have already told you.  If you don't understand what I've said then I give up.

Comment: If you try to send your data to a socket connected to nowhere, the writing call may well block. Execute step by step and see by yourself. Sending data from the GUI is awful but, at least initially, it could work well enough.